# laravel 4.0 : Eager loading error - Trying to get property of non-object while selecting condition

Tags: laravel-4, eager-loading

I am trying to display product on the category, and I use eager loading. how i can get it?

my table

1. product => 
   product_id | productCategory_id | etc
2. category =>
   category_id | name_category
3. productImage =>
   productImage_id | product_id | name_image

product is one to many with Category 
product is one to many with productImage

my product controller

```
$product = M_productImage::with(array('product' => function($query)
            {
                 $query->where('productCategory_id', '!=', 6);

            }))->orderBy('productImage_id','=', 'desc')->groupBy('product_id')->take(4)->get();
```

my view

```
<ul class="row list-unstyled" style="min-height: 442px;">
                    @foreach($product as $value)
                    <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-center animated">
                        <div class="product">
                            <figure class="figure-hover-overlay">                                                                        
                                <a href="#" class="figure-href"></a>

                                @if($value->product->status_product == 2)
                                <div class="product-new" style="width:100px !important;">Limited Stock</div>
                                @elseif($value->product->status_product == 3)
                                <div class="product-sale" style="width:100px !important;">Sold out</div>
                                @endif
                                <img width="400px" height="450px" class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('assets/image/product/medium/'.$value->productImage_name)}}" alt="" title="">
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <a href="#" title="Wishlist"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="shoping"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" title="Compare"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="product-caption" >
                                <p style="height:50px;"><a href="{{ URL::to('productdetail/'. $value->product->product_id ) }}" class="product-name">{{$value->product->title_product}}</a></p>
                                <p class="product-price"><span>{{$value->product->priceBefore}}</span> {{$value->product->priceAfter}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
```

I'm traying using dd($product) there is value in it and true, but i don't know what's wrong with my view, the view result is **Trying to get property of non-object**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solving using **whereHas**

```
    $id = 7;
    $product = M_productImage::whereHas('product', function($q) use ($id)
        {
               $q->where('productCategory_id','!=', $id);
        })->orderBy('productImage_id','=', 'desc')->groupBy('product_id')->take(4)->get();
```

show in [my pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PqAZU5S1)